# Setting Master/Detail's first appearance to the Master view, not the Detail view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This question has been asked a couple of times but I seem to have serious issues understanding the concept. This is how the part looks like right now

[image]
A TabBarController leads to the master on the left. Now, where am I supposed to put the `splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController . . .` in this setup? I tried it at numerous places, tried setting delegates, ... but it doesn't even get called. I can't even provide real code as there is nothing to show.

I got a class for the TableViewCell, one for the DetailViewController, and one for the TableViewController.

If anyone could point me at what point I should add abovementioned method so it gets called and prevents the app from jumping straight into the Detail view, I'd really appreciate that.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the missing part was not setting the delegate to what I've set the other controllers' delegates to.

I now have 2 masters (still no idea where the "template-created" master got the delegate-association from) and my new master's split view's delegate is the same file the other one uses. There, the `splitViewController . . .` gets called and I can manipulate with `return YES`.